# проверка данных при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, requests, bs4

При парсинге страницы (https://maxline.by/mstat.php?p=170888:105457:664287:11243120) на ней не всегда отражается полная информация ( 5 матчей каждой из команд). Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать проверку наличия всех игр. Тоесть если какой то матч отсутствует, как на данной страницы, то парсер выводин какойнибудь предупреждающий текс, а не выдает ошибку.

```
def get_html(url, params=None):
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup (html, 'html.parser')
    
    play = {
        'league': soup.find(class_='mstat__title').find('h1').find_all('b')[0].get_text(strip=True),
        'teams' : soup.find(class_='mstat__title').find('h1').find_all('b')[1].get_text(strip=True)
    }

    one = soup.find_all(class_='ev-mstat-tbl')[0]
    
    team_one = {
        'game1': one.find_all(target='_blank')[0].get_text(strip=True),
        'check1': one.find_all('td', class_='score')[0].get_text(strip=True),
        'game2': one.find_all(target='_blank')[1].get_text(strip=True),
        'check2': one.find_all('td', class_='score')[1].get_text(strip=True),
        'game3': one.find_all(target='_blank')[2].get_text(strip=True),
        'check3': one.find_all('td', class_='score')[2].get_text(strip=True),
        'game4': one.find_all(target='_blank')[3].get_text(strip=True),
        'check4': one.find_all('td', class_='score')[3].get_text(strip=True),
        'game5': one.find_all(target='_blank')[4].get_text(strip=True),
        'check5': one.find_all('td', class_='score')[4].get_text(strip=True),
    }

    two = one = soup.find_all(class_='ev-mstat-tbl')[1]
    team_two = {
        'game1': two.find_all(target='_blank')[0].get_text(strip=True),
        'check1': two.find_all('td', class_='score')[0].get_text(strip=True),
        'game2': two.find_all(target='_blank')[1].get_text(strip=True),
        'check2': two.find_all('td', class_='score')[1].get_text(strip=True),
        'game3': two.find_all(target='_blank')[2].get_text(strip=True),
        'check3': two.find_all('td', class_='score')[2].get_text(strip=True),
        'game4': two.find_all(target='_blank')[3].get_text(strip=True),
        'check4': two.find_all('td', class_='score')[3].get_text(strip=True),
        'game5': two.find_all(target='_blank')[4].get_text(strip=True),
        'check5': two.find_all('td', class_='score')[4].get_text(strip=True),
    }

    print(play)
    print(team_one)
    print(team_two)

parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

"парсер выводин какойнибудь предупреждающий текс, а не выдает ошибку." Для этого можно использовать `try-except`. Ну если граммотно написать код `try-except` могут не понадобится.
Как пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://maxline.by/mstat.php?p=170888:105457:664287:11243120')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

games = soup.find_all(class_='ev-mstat-tbl')
for one in games:
    title, *nat = one.find_all('tr')
    print(title.text.replace(' (23)', ''))
    print()
    #z = [nat[x] for x in range(0, len(nat), 2)]
    z = [x for i, x in enumerate(nat[2:], 1) if i % 2]
    for c in z:
        game, check = [x.text for x in c.find_all('td')]
        print(game.replace(' (23)', ''))
        print(check)
    print('-------')
```

вывод

```
Последние игры Венесуэла:

Венесуэла - Боливия
3:2 (31:33, 25:18, 24:26, 25:22, 15:11) 
Колумбия - Венесуэла
3:0 (25:23, 25:15, 25:18) 
Перу - Венесуэла
3:1 (25:22, 20:25, 26:24, 25:20) 
Венесуэла - Иран
0:3 (14:21, 21:23, 17:21) 
Аргентина - Венесуэла
0:3 (18:21, 14:21, 14:21) 
-------
Последние игры Боливия:

Венесуэла - Боливия
3:2 (31:33, 25:18, 24:26, 25:22, 15:11) 
Доминиканская Респ. - Боливия
3:2 (25:19, 21:25, 19:25, 25:23, 15:12) 
-------
```

Comment: а можно ли ответ записать в список в котором один матч будет картежем?